# I click on a button/link in a HTML file that links to another HTML file. If I have to do an alert (in the next file) after the click, how can I do it?

Tags: javascript, html

In firstdocument.html;

```
<button> <a href="seconddocument.html"> Click </a> </button>
```

In seconddocument.html,

```
alert();
```

Solution please.

Comment: You can't, have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

Normally it is not possible. But you can do it by passing query string and then write an alert based on the querystring value in Page load.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible.

You could create a javascript file and have both pages load that file.

Then when you "click" you can call the function.